# Delphi 7 how to do this?

Tags: delphi, function

So i have one StringGrid called StringGrid1 with FixedRow and Column set to 1,i have 6 Columns and 2 rows.
I have one edit button called EdBrUc,i have three buttons one BtUnesi, second Button1 and third Button 2 now i am supposed to do a function,with adding three numbers together then well here is the function

```
function tform1.sabiranje(a, b, c: tniz): real;
var
  sab: real;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    sab := (a[i] + b[i] + c[i]) / 3;
  end;
  sabiranje := sab;
end;
```

so with that done,
i am supposed to use that to "see" what grade did the student get?
One test can have 100 points,so three tests = Max point = 300 and then if i / 3 it is 100 so that is  the highest number of points a student can have.

now i am supposed to write that into the sixth column of the String Grid 
so

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  clan, ocenaa: real;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[2, i]);
    a[i] := clan;
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[3, i]);
    b[i] := clan;
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[4, i]);
    c[i] := clan;

    begin
      ocenaa := sabiranje(a, b, c);
      if StringGrid1.Cells[5, i] = 'pao' then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '5'
      else if (ocenaa > 50) and (ocenaa < 64) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '6'
      else if (ocenaa > 64) and (ocenaa < 74) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '7'
      else if (ocenaa > 74) and (ocenaa < 84) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '8'
      else if (ocenaa > 84) and (ocenaa < 94) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '9'
      else if (ocenaa = 100) and (ocenaa > 94) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '10';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

for some reason it just wont work...here is the WHOLE CODE.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Grids;

type
  tniz = array [1 .. 300] of real;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    EdBrUc: TEdit;
    LbBrUc: TLabel;
    BtUnesi: TButton;
    Button1: TButton;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    Button2: TButton;
    function sabiranje(a, b, c: tniz): real;
    procedure BtUnesiClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  a, b, c: tniz;
  n: integer;
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm1.sabiranje(a, b, c: tniz): real;
var
  sab: real;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    sab := (a[i] + b[i] + c[i]) / 3;
  end;
  sabiranje := sab;
end;

procedure TForm1.BtUnesiClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  n := StrToInt(EdBrUc.Text);
  StringGrid1.RowCount := n + 1;
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, 0] := 'Rb';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, 0] := 'Ime i prezime';
  StringGrid1.Cells[2, 0] := 'Kolokvijum 1';
  StringGrid1.Cells[3, 0] := 'Kolokvijum 2';
  StringGrid1.Cells[4, 0] := 'Kolokvijum 3';
  StringGrid1.Cells[5, 0] := 'Pao ili prosao';
  StringGrid1.Cells[6, 0] := 'Ocena';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  clan, ocena: real;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[2, i]);
    a[i] := clan;
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[3, i]);
    b[i] := clan;
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[4, i]);
    c[i] := clan;

    if (a[i] > 50) and (b[i] > 50) and (c[i] > 50) then
      StringGrid1.Cells[5, i] := 'prosao'
    else
      StringGrid1.Cells[5, i] := 'pao';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  clan, ocenaa: real;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[2, i]);
    a[i] := clan;
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[3, i]);
    b[i] := clan;
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[4, i]);
    c[i] := clan;
    begin
      ocenaa := sabiranje(a, b, c);
      if StringGrid1.Cells[5, i] = 'pao' then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '5'
      else if (ocenaa > 50) and (ocenaa < 64) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '6'
      else if (ocenaa > 64) and (ocenaa < 74) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '7'
      else if (ocenaa > 74) and (ocenaa < 84) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '8'
      else if (ocenaa > 84) and (ocenaa < 94) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '9'
      else if (ocenaa = 100) and (ocenaa > 94) then
        StringGrid1.Cells[6, i] := '10';
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "it just wont work". Describe clearly the behaviour you expect and the behaviour that you observe.

Comment: Well what the function should do is add that three numbers so from 1 to 100 as that can be the number of points and then it should divide it by 3 so the final score can be from 1 to 100 also,and then from 50 to 64 the grade is 6 from 64 to 74 the grade is 7 from 74 to 84 the grade is 8 etc. and we get to 94 to 100 the grade is 10

by clicking on first button(BtUnesi) we get the number of rows(it is from 1 to n,differs on number of students) on second button(Button1) it shows did he pass or not,and when i click on third button(which is related to function) it wont work... -.-

Comment: "How to do this?" is not a suitable question here. What exactly would that be useful for in a search on this site for someone in the future? Please [edit] your question and make the title more meaningful. Thanks.

Comment: Only read the first snippet, you're assigning 'sab' to '1 to n' times, you're not keeping 'sab's anywwhere, not summing or anything. Only the last assignment prevails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is useless. You get allways the values of `sab:=(a[n]+b[n]+c[n])/3;`
You overwriting from 1 to n allways `sab` and getting only "if i=n" the last value.

```
function  tform1.sabiranje(a,b,c:tniz):real;
var
sab:real;
i:integer;

begin
 for i:=1 to n do
 begin
  sab:=(a[i]+b[i]+c[i])/3;
 end;
 sabiranje:=sab;
end;
```

I do not know exactly what you're doing.
But i think you want only add 1 row of .cells.

```
function  tform1.sabiranje(a,b,c:tniz; at:integer):real;

begin
  result := (a[at]+b[at]+c[at])/3;
end;
```

get it with

```
 for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[2, i]);
    a[i] := clan;
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[3, i]);
    b[i] := clan;
    clan := StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[4, i]);
    c[i] := clan;

    ocenaa := sabiranje(a, b, c, i);
 [...]
```

if you just want to values from 95 to 100, that's wrong.

```
if (ocenaa=100) and (ocenaa>94) then StringGrid1.Cells[6,i]:='10';
```

Should be

```
if (ocenaa < 101) and (ocenaa>94) then StringGrid1.Cells[6,i]:='10';
```

And remember you are dealing with real

94.0000001 > 94

You should Round it.

```
 function Round ( const Number : Extended ) : Int64;
```

[Delphi how to Round](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Round)